# Why will my custom background image work on the iPhone, but not iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, background, set, uitableview

In my app delegate I am setting the view background of the view controller like this:

```
navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneBackground.png"]];
```

And it works really well when i am running my iPhone app, but when I build it as an iPad app (its a universal application) the background is just gray.

The views that I am trying to get the image to set are simple drill down views of a uitableview. I just can't get an iPad image to show...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the view's frame to be 1024x1024 before applying the background pattern

Comment: how to do that using IB?

Answer (score 0):

try setting tableView.backgroundView = nil